# Can notepad be replaced with VS code?

Tags: windows, sublime-text-3, notepad, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to replace Microsoft Notepad on Windows 10 as the default editor with VS Code?

This repo (https://github.com/grumpydev/Sublime-Notepad-Replacement) shows how it's possible to replace Notepad with Sublime Text, but I wonder if this is possible with VS Code?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but why would you want that system wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it so a specific file type will open in a specific application.

**Windows 10:**

1. On the **Start  menu**, select **Settings**
2. Select **Apps** > **Default apps**.
3. Select which default you want to set, and then choose the app. You can also get new apps in Microsoft Store. Apps need to be installed before you can set them as the default. Choose default apps under Apps in Settings
4. To choose default apps by file type (for example, .pdf files), scroll down and select **Choose default apps by file type.**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs

**Windows 7**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs

Comment: unfortunately vscode is not registered for text editing so it will not appear in the list - if it wasnt installed through ms store (which is never the case)

Comment: check here https://superuser.com/a/1568720/521549

Comment: @edoardo Evidently it worked at some point but things change as Windows gets updates. And it must have worked at the time because the answer was accepted by the OP.