# Windows 10 not associating filetypes with applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, file-types

Going into any given files properties, and changing the "open with" property has not affect on anything that isn't a default windows application.

Example: https://gph.is/2yV5dRY

[image: and here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Notepad++ default program for \`.txt\` files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1324367/how-can-i-make-notepad-default-program-for-txt-files)

Comment: See also [Unable to associate .txt file with listed Visual Studio Code on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1367659/150988).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS wont give up file associations](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations)

Answer (score 1):

It's a know bug. Windows 10 V1803 is affected. Several blogs and websites are starting to report it. I have this issue too. No matter which way you tryo, you cannot set the file association to some softwares (in my case I can't set jpeg to Adobe Bridge, for example).
Hopefully MS will fix it in the next patch. Until then you'll have to live with the problem.

Comment: I don't know who down voted but this is definitely the correct answer, while the other answer is a work around that doesn't actually fix the issue.

Comment: I upvoted because the downvote wasn't legitimate. This is the correct answer introduced in the [17134.345 build](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462919/windows-10-update-kb4462919). Microsoft claims to be `working on a resolution and estimates a solution will be available in late November 2018` but I bet they will be late to provide a fix

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** -> **Apps** -> **Default apps** -> **Choose default apps by file type**.  There, you can change the default app based on file extension.